# Data control for cell

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I want to do. I have five columns (A,B,C,D,E). My requirement is that in each row, only one cell should accept data, and the remaining cells should not accept data (i.e. the remaining four cells should be in locked mode).

eg if the user enter 1 in column 1, BCDE will be lock but if the user decides to change the option they can put back original data and change to another value in a column. Below is a sample of what I am trying to do.

```
VeryStrong   Strong   Neutral   Weak   VeryWeak
1              0        0        0        0      Data keyed by user 1
0              1        0        0        0      Data keyed by user 2
0              1        1        0        0      *This is what I am trying to prevent*
```

User 1 can go back and change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Unprotect
    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        'Data was added in target cell. Lock its neighbours.
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 5).Locked = True
        Target.Locked = False
    Else
        'Data was erased from target cell. Release its neighbours.
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 5).Locked = False
    End If
    Me.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use [radio/option buttons](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/add-a-check-box-option-button-or-toggle-button-to-a-worksheet-HP010236677.aspx)? :)

Comment: No Form/ActiveX controls required. The easiest would be to use `Worksheet_Change`event.

Comment: See the `X` example at the end of the post [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658251/make-only-one-checkbox-tickable-in-a-row/19658354#19658354)

Comment: There is a value attached to it as there are point involved. I am looking at the Worksheet_Change event. I got this

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Unprotect
    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        'Data was added in target cell. Lock its neighbours.
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 4).Locked = True
        Target.Locked = False
    Else
        'Data was erased from target cell. Release its neighbours.
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 4).Locked = False
    End If
    Me.Protect
End Sub

Comment: I am trying to figure out the code and change the relevant to specific columns eg K9,L9,M9,N9,O9.

Comment: Can't read code in comments. Please update your question with the code

Comment: also i have a quick question. Let's say the user enters `1` in `very strong`. this would lock the rest of the cells. but the user then realizes, he wanted to enter `1` in `Strong`. So now what would he do as the rest of the cells are locked? MY SUGGESTION: Don't lock the cells. ensure that user cannot enter multiple data.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490084/optionbutton-index-issue) may be helpful (low importance)

Comment: Or if you want if the user inputs `0` back in the cell then that will unlock the entire range

Comment: Yup Siddharth. I am looking at your suggestion as the default value is 0. so if there is a mistake he will need to enter 0 first at the original entry before proceeding.

Comment: Tks santosh. will check it out

Comment: Why did you take out your code from your question?

Comment: sorry first time on this site. figuring out the functions

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out the code and change the relevant to specific columns eg K9,L9,M9,N9,O9. – Timothy Teoh 27 mins ago

Try this. (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyPass As String
    Dim Rw As Long

    MyPass = "Sid" '<~~ Change this to your password

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:O")) Is Nothing Then
        Rw = Target.Row

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect MyPass

        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is > 0
            Range("K" & Rw & ":O" & Rw).Locked = True
            Target.Locked = False
        Case 0
            Range("K" & Rw & ":O" & Rw).Locked = False
        End Select
    End If

Letscontinue:
    ActiveSheet.Protect MyPass
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

[image]